Norm of Lipschitz-free space
Let (M, d) be a pointed metric space with distinguished point 0 and $\mathcal{F} (M) $ be the corresponding Lipschitz-free spaces. That means, $\mathcal{F} (M) =\overline{\operatorname {span}} \{\frac{\delta_{x}- \delta_{y}} {d(x, y)} : x, y\in M, x\neq y\} $,
where $\delta_x : \operatorname {Lip}_0(M) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $\delta_x (f) =f(x) $
and $\operatorname {Lip}_0(M) =\{ \text{ Lipschitz map } f \text{ on } M : f(0)=0\}$ is a Banach space with respect to Lipschitz norm.
Let $\mu \in \operatorname {span}\{\frac{\delta_{x}- \delta_{y}} {d(x, y)} : x, y\in M, x\neq y\} $. Define
$\|\mu\|_1 := \sup\{f(\mu) : f \in \operatorname {Lip}_0(M), \|f\|_{\operatorname {Lip}_0(M)} \leq 1\}$
$\|\mu\|_2 := \inf\{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} |a_i| : \mu = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} a_i \frac{\delta_{x_i}- \delta_{y_i}} {d(x_i, y_i)} \} $
How to show that $\|\mu\|_1 = \|\mu\|_2$.
I know $\|\mu\|_1 \leq \|\mu\|_2$. I don't know how to show the other inequality is also true.
